# IE8 crashing opening WordPress with Gantry Framework installed

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-8, crash

I got a problem that's driving me up the wall: I made a Wordpress Blog, using the Gantry framework for layout en several different widgets and plugins. Everything works fine in FF, Safari, and Chrome, but trying to open the site with IE 8 the browser crashes or in the best cases I get a message that the tab has been closed and reopened due to an error; after which the site is loaded fine. I try finding out what happens during the opening of the page, but the debug panel of IE doesn't point out any error!
Does anybody have clue on what the problem might be?

The website is: http://www.danielevecchiotti.it/

Comment: I agree; that would be the best solution; unfortunatly I cannot forse all the people in the world to use Chrome or FF ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem: the site has been HACKED!

I noticed the `index.php` and `wp-blog-header.php` files modified on a strange date and time. Downloading the two files I found they had been compromised: a whole section of unreadable code had been added. Uploading the original PHP files the above problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from the same attack today, so I investigated a bit:

That injection is done through the hole in one of the plugins, most likely through the outdated contact-form-7 plugin. Check if you have this folder in your wp-content/plugins directory - even if it is not activated in Wordpress, the very presence of it there is a potential security threat as the attacker can use the direct URL of the plugin faulty file to access it.

(source: http://wewatchyourwebsite.com/wordpress/2011/11/wordpress-websites-infected-through-outdated-contact-form-7-plugin)

**Patching the hole:** if you use this plugin, update it to the latest version which is not vulnerable. If you don't use it and just keep it deactivated (like I did), you can remove it at all.

It is also a good idea to prevent people from accessing your plugins directly. You can create a wp-content/plugins/.htaccess with the following content:

```
<Files *.php>
  deny from all
</Files>
```

This might not work with every configuration, but usually plugins are only accessed in the code, not with HTTP calls so that shouldn't do harm to visitors' experience.

**Restoring your site:** If you don't have backup of your *.php files to restore them all from by overwriting your current ones, you need to search for every file containing the string specific to the malicious code, e.g. "eva1fYlbakBcVSir". Then you need to edit all those files - for every file, remove a long  line from it's end.

Or if you're proficient with command line and, say, perl, you can build a regular expression to do the work for you.

**What was the purpose of the attack?** Obviously there were links to some Java plugin added to your site's pages by those code snippets. The plugin added is believed to be the following: http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/Threat/Encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?name=Exploit%3aJava%2fCVE-2010-0840.KM&threatid=2147649278

However, I didn't manage yet to decipher the injected code fully - it's very well messed up and the reverse engineering is hard. So I can't tell for sure that apart from showing that Java plugin to visitors the exploit was doing nothing like reading users' passwords or removing some files (unlikely, but possible).

I can't find any information about that as well, looks like nobody traced the consequences fully yet.

Please share if you know more.